# Prevent Solr from printing query in console

Tags: solr, jetty, solrj

I have quite long queries and I would like Solr to not print the full query request in the console where I started solr from. 
Where should I look to modify this?

I have tried to modify the logging level in etc/logging.properties and add

```
-Djava.util.logging.config.file=etc/logging.properties
```

when stating solr, but it has no effect.

Thanks

Comment: Finally I had to modify resources/log4j.properties

Comment: Why not add your comment as answer and self-accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I had to modify resources/log4j.properties